# Cannot exit audit mode after upgrade to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, sysprep, windows-8-upgrade, windows-audit-mode

I accidentally entered audit mode from OOBE after upgrading to Windows 8, and now i get this message:

[image: Sysprep cannot run on a computer that has been upgraded to a new version of Windows. You can only run Sysprep on a custom (clean) install version of Windows.].

How do i get my system back to usable state?

Comment: I assume you meant audit mode. Windows 8 hasn’t turned 18 yet — it will go out of support long before that.

Comment: Actual this messege is shown when i type "C:/windows/system32/sysprep/sysprep.exe /oobe /reboot"

Comment: Um, can you post a text equivalent? Imgur (the SE image uploader) is blocked from where I am.

Comment: Message equivalent for thoes who are blocked from imgur http://i57.tinypic.com/14u86yo.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I point to you all i upgraded, to just simple Windows 8.0. Simple another upgrade to Windows 8.1 fixed it, no more auto boot to audit mode, it showed OOBE like normal installation, and no noticible upgrade progress loss.